# Function that sorts multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-inspection

I need to write a function `sort_gradebook(gradebook)`, which has next arguments: `[first_name, last_name, grade_1, grade_2, ..., grade_n, final_grade]`. Function must sort by:

- Final grade
- If final grades are equal - by first grade
- If first grades are equal - by second grade, etc
- If all grades are equal - by second name
- If second names are equal - by name.

Everything I could do:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def sort_gradebook(*gradebook):
    length = len([str(i) for i in gradebook[0]])
    a = [i for i in range(length)]
    for i in a:
        s = sorted(gradebook, key = itemgetter(i))

    return s
```

For test:

```
from itertools import permutations

def test_sort(inp, outp):
    for i in permutations(inp):
        assert sort_gradebook(list(i)) == outp

test_sort([['Alice', 'Smith', 2, 3, 4],
    ['John', 'Smith', 2, 3, 5]], [['John', 'Smith', 2, 3, 5],
    ['Alice', 'Smith', 2, 3, 4]
])
```

Comment: So, the number of grades can change?

Comment: You miss to `reverse` as John has higher final grade and comes first

Comment: @Mandera No, it's not. I already saw thos answers. They are good for 2 arguments, but doesn't work with more... or I didn't get how to use it for multiple arguments... anyway, I would be thankful, if someone can explain, how to apply that answer to my question.

Comment: @SultanTapi Oh okay I see how you can think that. The thing you missed is that the `key` parameter of `sort` can handle a tuple, which means that you can have infinite keys, not only two like they use in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sorting

- you want to sort on multiple parameters, that are the different indices. You can use `itemgetter(0,1,2)`, and in your case `itemgetter(4,3,2,1,0)` which need to be built dynamically regarding the size
- add `reverse=True` to get John, who has higher final grade, before Alice

```
def sort_gradebooks(*gradebooks):
    nb_attributes = len(gradebooks[0])
    s = itemgetter(*[i for i in range(nb_attributes - 1, -1, -1)]) # itemgetter(4,3,2,1,0)
    return sorted(gradebooks, key=s, reverse=True)
```

## Call it

You need to call the sort with `*i` and `i` to pass the flatten the parameters and not pass one list, but rather multiple items

```
def test_sort(inp, outp):
    for i in permutations(inp):
        print(sort_gradebooks(*i) == outp)
```

---

```
print(sort_gradebooks(*[['Alice', 'Smith', 2, 3, 4], ['John', 'Smith', 2, 3, 5]])) # John / Alice because final grade
print(sort_gradebooks(*[['Alice', 'Smith', 2, 3, 5], ['John', 'Smith', 2, 3, 5]])) # John / Alice because name
print(sort_gradebooks(*[['Alice', 'Smith', 2, 5, 5], ['John', 'Smith', 2, 3, 5]])) # Alice / John because 2ng grade
```

Comment: Thank you! Bueatiful code! Could you please explain, itemgetter(4,3,2,1,0) starts to sort from ind(4)?

Comment: @SultanTapi 0,1,2,3,4 are the indices of each value of `['Alice', 'Smith', 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: i know.  s = itemgetter(*[i for i in range(nb_attributes - 1, -1, -1)]) # itemgetter(4,3,2,1,0) - sorting starts from index 4, then 3, 2, 1 and 0?

Comment: @SultanTapi yes

Comment: Thanks! last question: i read somewhere, that if you want to sort by several arguments, you must to start from earliest to the latest, for example in ['Alice', 'Smith', 1, 3, 5], ['John', 'Smith', 2, 3, 5], first you must sort by ind(0), then(1), etc. is it right? if yes, how your sorting works, if it starts from ind(4)?

Comment: @SultanTapi you said you want to start by sorting n Final grade, and end on Name so .. ?

Comment: exactly. before i started this task, i read rules, how to sort. they wrote about such cases, like, if you need to sort multiple arguments beginning from index(last), you need to sort first index(0), then index(1), ..., index(last). thats why i was surprised, when saw your solution, because your code starts to sort from ind(last). i guess, the rule i read wasn't correct?

Comment: @SultanTapi If you want to sort by name then by final grade you would have done `itemgetter(0,4)` OR, by grade and if grade same by name : `itemgetter(4,0)` you asked by **final grade** first, so it comes fist in the itemgetter